# Group by - Sign vs Group by - Parity

Tags: microsoft-powerbi

This may sound like a silly question but I searched MS KB and have been searching for 2 days now in google.

I want to understand the difference between `Group by - Sign` and `Group by - Parity`. I believe Parity is `Even / Odd`. But what is Sign? Sign as in `+ / -` or is it something else?

I am using Power BI Desktop and this feature is part of `Column Profile`

**Power BI Desktop Version**: 2.119.986.0 32-bit (July, 2023)

[image]